# Deploying Rshiny.app - requires at least one document?

Tags: r, shinyapps

I do not understand, why I receive this message after trying to deploy my first app:

```
> Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 8874124...Fehler in inferAppPrimaryDoc(appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, appFiles = appFiles,  : 
  Application mode static requires at least one document.
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... withStatus -> force -> bundleApp -> inferAppPrimaryDoc
Ausführung angehalten
```

What I did:

1. So I designed an app.
   [image]

The weird thing is also the logo that I provided by the "www" folder as png.file that randomly vanished. It was there in the morning. I haven't changed anything in the code..

2. Then I created an account on shinyapps.io
3. I connected my shinyapps.io with R
   [image]
4. I ran the deploy.app() - and failed
   I clicked the publish button manually (when you click "Run App") -and failed.
5. And now I tried another way via:
   [image]
   I needed to split R scripts into 2 files (ui.R and server.R)
   It is still running. But it seems to go further than before. Do not know the outcome yet.

[image]
It seems working now. So I need to split R scripts? I thought it does not matter as long as I name functions correctly.

Cheers,
Nadine

Comment: This is not something we can see or reproduce. Can you add more context so that we can try it, or at least to see what was attempted? At a minimum, create a very simple shiny app (or rmarkdown document) and include the code you use to deploy it.

Comment: I don't think it is the actual code that has an error. I think I do a mistake in deploying. 
Because I can run it on my server.

Comment: Okay ... but we don't know _how_ you are deploying it. Also, it can depend on file names and other things in/around the app file(s) itself. Please try to paint us a more detailed picture (even if without code) so that we can see what you tried and what file structure you expect to be deploying.